# Batch File for Xml modification

Tags: batch-file

i have an xml file on which i have to do modification basing on some rules and i want to know can we do that in the batch script. suppose the following is the sample of xml file

```
> > <conf-article article-type="research" content-type="----"
> > dtd-version="---" open-access="no" xml:lang="en" lifecycle="final">
> > <conf-front>
    <conf-proc-meta>
    <conf-proc-id
> > conf-proc-id-type="conf-acronym">cccc</conf-proc-id>
> > <conf-proc-title-group>
```

and i want to insert the following lines

```
<!--Delivery Date: 07/23/2013-->
<!--XML Script: sdfasdfdfs-->
<!--Batch: sdfsdfdssfs-->
```

before `<conf-front>` tag.This is an example like that i have some more.so i need some help on this.

Comment: Is `<conf-front>` always the `third` line? Are lines 1 and 2 always the same or are they dynamic?

Comment: It can be either 4th or 5th line always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @echo off

    ::get the line before desired tag
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /n "<conf-front>" some.xml') do set /a line=%%L-1

    ::create empty file 
    break>"%temp%\empty"

    ::get first <%line%> lines of the file 
    fc "%temp%\empty" "some.xml" /lb  %line% /t |more +4 | findstr /B /E /V "*****" >temp.xml

    :: add additional content
    echo ^<!--Delivery Date: 07/23/2013--^>  >> temp.xml
    echo ^<!--XML Script: sdfasdfdfs--^>  >> temp.xml
    echo ^<!--Batch: sdfsdfdssfs--^>  >> temp.xml

    ::get last <%line%> lines of the file
    type "some.xml" | more +%line%  >> temp.xml

    ::delete temp empty file
    del /Q /F "%temp%\empty"
```

This will create temp.xml file and you can check if it fits on your needs and then copy it over your old file.Will set this before **last** `<conf-front>` tag so I hope there's only one of this kind.And change `some.xml` with the name of your xml everywhere in the code.

**EDIT** ~ do this with all .xml in a folder (will not affect subfolders)

```
 @echo off

 rem cd /d "c:\some_dir"

::create empty file 
break>"%temp%\empty"

:: iterate trough the xml files
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%X in (*.xml) do (


    set "line="
    ::get the line before desired tag
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /n "<conf-front>" %%~dpsnxX') do set /a line=%%L-1

    ::only in case the tag is presented
    if defined line (

        ::get first <%line%> lines of the file 
        fc "%temp%\empty" "%%~dpsnxX" /lb  !line! /t |more +4 | findstr /B /E /V "*****" >%temp%\temp.%%~nX.xml

        :: add additional content
        echo ^<^^!--Delivery Date: 07/23/2013--^>  >>"%temp%\temp.%%~nX.xml"
        echo ^<^^!--XML Script: sdfasdfdfs--^>  >>"%temp%\temp.%%~nX.xml"
        echo ^<^^!--Batch: sdfsdfdssfs--^>  >>"%temp%\temp.%%~nX.xml"

        ::get last <%line%> lines of the file
        type "%%~dpsnxX" | more +!line!  >>"%temp%\temp.%%~nX.xml"

    )

)
endlocal

:: replace the file with these in temp folder with new content
for %%X in (*.xml) do (
    move /Y "%temp%\temp.%%~nX.xml" "%%~dpnxX" 2>nul
)

::delete temp empty file
del /Q /F "%temp%\empty"
```

Just change `c:\some_dir` with your own path.And back-up your dir..

Comment: I have 100 xml files in one folder with different names so how to run this code to change all the xml files.

Comment: Can you check it now?

Comment: Hi i have tried using your code with the changes u have told to do. But i am getting the following error as                         Cannot access file F:\Documents and Settings\sys\Desktop\test1\+
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
FC: Invalid Switch

Comment: This will happen if you have a file without this tag.I'll edit it again :-)

Comment: but all my files definitely will have the tag of <conf-front>

Comment: Could you check it the new `last` version?? Tested also with a file without the tag.

Comment: Just a comment to say that `FC` is not a reliable tool in text mode.

Comment: In all cases the script is more robust now...With `find "<conf-front>" *.xml`  you can check if all files has it.

Comment: It is inserting but at the closing tag of </conf-front> and the remaining content after that is getting deleted. I want just to keep that text at the place

Comment: @foxidrive - I'm not doing a real compare , but only using it to show the first lines of a file.

Comment: will test it and see how can be fixed.edit: Nothing like this happens with me 0_o.Could share some of the files somewhere?

Comment: i have sent the sample file to you

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q19559569.xml) DO (
  ECHO("%%a"|FIND "<conf-front>" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO(^<!--Delivery Date: 07/23/2013--^>
    ECHO(^<!--XML Script: sdfasdfdfs--^>
    ECHO(^<!--Batch: sdfsdfdssfs--^>
  )
  ECHO(%%a
 )
)>newfile.xml
GOTO :EOF
```

where q19559569.xml is your original and newfile.xml is created.

Batch is really not a suitable tool for the task.

I've assumed that by "before" you mean "on the line preceding that on which the nominated tag appears" and not "directly before the tag" - that is, between the leading `> >` and the tag.

Since the inserted text nominated is clearly artificial, if the real text you require is placed in a file called say `insertme.txt` then replacing the three `ECHO` statements with

```
type insertme.txt
```

should be more flexible.

---

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%x IN (*.xml) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('type "%%x"') DO (
  ECHO("%%a"|FIND "<conf-front>" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO(^<!--Delivery Date: 07/23/2013--^>
    ECHO(^<!--XML Script: sdfasdfdfs--^>
    ECHO(^<!--Batch: sdfsdfdssfs--^>
  )
  ECHO(%%a
 )
)>"%%~nx.new"
GOTO :EOF
```

This mod should produce a new file with extension `.new` from the existing `.xml` files

Comment: if i want the script itself to run for all xml files in the folder then ? and it should write to the same file and the remaining content should not be removed.

Comment: Really need to be much more specific. Do you want to run on all .xmls producing a new file corresponding to EACH individual .xml, or one gigantic .xml containing all of the data from your original set, each adjusted? This batch should not change anything other than injecting the three lines before the line(s) containing `<conf-front>` You could check using `FC your.xml newfile.xml`

Comment: no not one gigantic xml file. It should write in the corresponding file nonly

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to process a folder full of xml files.

It uses a helper batch file by Aacini called `findrepl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file, and remove the `REM` to make the `.tmp` version of the files overwrite the original files, after you test it.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.xml) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
      type "%%a" |findrepl "." /e:"<conf-front>" /o:-1:-1 >"%%a.tmp"
         >>"%%a.tmp" echo ^<!--Delivery Date: 07/23/2013--^>
         >>"%%a.tmp" echo ^<!--XML Script: sdfasdfdfs--^>
         >>"%%a.tmp" echo ^<!--Batch: sdfsdfdssfs--^>
      type "%%a" |findrepl /v "." /e:"<conf-front>" /o:-1:-1 >>"%%a.tmp"
   REM move "%%a.tmp" "%%a"
)
pause
```